# How to remove iframe when click to button

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a script  , if you put it in your website , it will insert iframe to your website 
the iframe calls a quiz webpage   this quiz page will be above your website, and cover it all if you answer the quiz correctly the quiz page should be removed .. so i do all things , but i can't remove the iframe when he finished the questions in order to see the original website .

This is a sample of what i want .

I have two pages , the first is the parent  and the second is the child 
I want to know how to remove an iframe when i click on a button that is inside the child page ;

Parent

```html
<!DOCtype>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  Parent
  <iframe id="frame" src="child.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And the child

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      function myFunction() {
        var getframe = document.getElementById("frame");
        getframe.innerHTML = '';
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this error

> myFunction is not defined

I tried many ways but no one works

Comment: Your function ``myFunction`` is not globally accessible, because it's part of your ``onload`` function. Have you tried to move it to the top of your ``<script>``?

Comment: I tried it ,  i got this error
Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: The purpose is to executes the js from the child , not the parent

Comment: I updated the post , could you see it again

Answer (score 2):

As in the comments, your function is only visible inside onload.

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
       var getframe = document.getElementById("frame");
       getframe.innerHTML = '';
    }
    function delFrame() {
       var getframe = document.getElementById("frame");
       getframe.remove();
    }
    function hideFrame() {
       var getframe = document.getElementById("frame");
       getframe.style.display = 'none';
    }
    function showFrame() {
       var getframe = document.getElementById("frame");
       getframe.style.display = 'block';
    }
    window.onload = function() {
      myFunction();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe id="frame" src="child.html"></iframe>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
  <button onclick="delFrame()">Delete Frame</button>
  <button onclick="hideFrame()">Hide Frame</button>
  <button onclick="showFrame()">Show Frame</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: The function is called **onload** AND **button click**.

Comment: I tried it ,  i got this error
Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Your code`document.getElementById("frame")`returns null, because there is no **frame (element)** to get by this id

Comment: I added the missig code/element (and some more) to the snippet!

Comment: What i want , while i am opening the parent page   if i  click on the button  , the iframe should be removed .

Comment: Is this should be the parent page or child page ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135289/discussion-between-saifaldeen-and-ben).